# The sun rises “east.”

Tags: adjuncts

> The sun rises “**east**.”

“*East*” can have this meaning: “[*in the east*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/east?s=t).” Then can the sentence above be used?

Comment: Actually I think the sun rises "up". In any case, do you have some context/source for your example? By itself it is hard to say if it is OK or not.

Comment: @user3169, there's no context, it's just from my curiosity whether 'the sun rises in the east' can be equivalent to 'the sun rises east.'

Comment: I wouldn't say 'the sun rises east' - in that case I would say 'the sun rises eastward'.

Comment: You link says it can mean _located in the east_, that is not the same as _in the east_. It can mean _located in the east_ as in _the east side_. This is a _static_ notion: the side that is _located in the east_. You cannot apply that to the sun rising. Be careful when reading dictionary definitions :)

Comment: The sense of "from the East" applies to _wind_, which travels _horizontally_.  so an East wind comes from the east an blows westward, while a West wind comes from the west and blows eastward. As others pointed out, the sun doesn't do this—it _rises_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a verb of motion is followed by a direction, it is interpreted as the direction of that motion and not as a location where the motion takes place.  Thus, the sun rises in the east, and it rises up into the sky.  It does not "rise east", which is a nonsensical phrase—it would mean that the direction of its rising was eastward rather than upward.

Answer (score 2):

Use "The sun rises in the east" instead.

["The sun rises east" is simply not said](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sun%20rises%20east%2Csun%20rises%20in%20the%20east&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csun%20rises%20east%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csun%20rises%20in%20the%20east%3B%2Cc0), for whatever reason; to my ear it sounds like it would mean that the sun rises toward the east, which isn't true.

Answer (score 2):

The normal thing is "The sun rises in the east" (1). After verbs of movement you can shorten indications of direction as in "The ship headed east".  In (1) "in the east" is a where-indication and not a where-to-indication. Where-indications are not shortened.

Answer (score 1):

East is also an adverb that is normally used to mean "towards the east" or to refer to the direction of movement to the east, a few examples are as follows:

1- My house faces east.

2- We drove east for two hours.

The sun rises east doesn't sound natural, although the adverb "east" also means in the east according to some English dictionaries. We always hear "the sun rises in the east".

Answer (score -1):

You only capitalize a proper noun - a name used for an individual person, place, or organization.  You do not need to put it in parenthesis either.

This is absolutely fine:

The sun rises in the east.